# Best practices of making RSA/AES keys password protected in android app

Tags: android, security, encryption, password-protection, android-keystore

I am developing secure SMS messaging app, and all the data is encrypted using AES key which is derived from RSA keys. I want to make the app password protected and thus these keys password protected, so that in no way it would be possible to extract keys without the password even if device is rooted and etc. So I plan to make user to enter password on app start/resume, if password is correct, extract keys, store in ram, use keys; when app is closed/destroyed, delete keys.

I thought to use keystore, however don't understand how secure it is.

It's written in https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html that:
If the app's process is compromised, the attacker may be able to use the app's keys but will not be able to extract their key material (for example, to be used outside of the Android device).
and
If the Android OS is compromised or an attacker can read the device's internal storage, the attacker may be able to use any app's Android Keystore keys on the Android device, but not extract them from the device.

What does it really mean?

What would be correct and secure way to solve my problem?

Comment: If you want to protect your apps' data with a password (especially if you are trying to protect against root), you should derive an encryption key using the password; as opposed to allowing access if the password is correct. This is because root can easily read the encryption keys from disk and then decrypt the data. In the case of the KeyStore, root can just request the KeyStore decrypt the data. If you're worried about root, then its already game over.

Answer (score 1):

In brief, the Keystore allows your application treat encryption and decryption like a black box; your application can specify the operation, the algorithm, even the key id, but cannot observe, or interfere with, the operation itself. This prevents an attacker, even one with control of your application process, from being able to steal your keys; they can perform encryption/decryption arbitrarily on the device, but cannot see the actual keys being used. Of course, a sufficiently well-funded and motivated attacker would be able to extract the keys eventually, but your users are unlikely to be faced with such an attacker unless they have raised the ire of a good-sized government.

In your scenario, storing your keys in the Keychain would be an effective way to mitigate the risk of most attackers, even ones with direct access to the device, stealing the keys your application uses. It is a much more secure solution than storing them in the filesystem, or hard-coding them. For the scenario you describe, it should be more than sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. Can I encrypt the keystore with password (different to unlock pin)?

Comment: As far as I am aware, you cannot.

Comment: Just to make it clear, this is **not** a solution for when an attacker has root. Root can simply request the KeyStore to decrypt the previously encrypted data.